# Sequelize upsert returns undefined _previousDataValues

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, upsert

I used Model.upsert function in sequelize. This method returns [record, created] that the record field is the upserted instance. I called this function with the exact duplicate data from database and in the return result, all the fields in _previousDataValues are undefined and the _changed Set contains all the fields.

I need a way to understand which fields have been changed (in this case zero fields because data is duplicate) without using a find query.
One way is to compare _previousDataValues with dataValues but all the fields _previousDataValues are undefined. Another way would be through _changed but the _changed contains all fields although no field has been changed.

I'd appreciate if someone helps me to get the changed fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_previousDataValues` stores values that were before you call `set` method of a mode  instance to change some values, see [set](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#instance-method-set).
`_previousDataValues` is not intended to get previous values from DB after an UPDATE query was executed.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I understood my mistake about _previousDataValues. Can you also help me about is there any way to get the changed fields without writing two queries (upsert and find) ?

Comment: I suppose PostgreSQL can't do such trick. You can try to get updated model instance from `upsert` method and additionally indicate `returning: true` in options.